# Column values truncated when using "Select Distinct" instead of "Select DistinctRow"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

The .Description column is a "MEMO" type.

Is it possible to retrieve the full value of DocketEntriedFiledBy.Description column when using DISTINCT?

It seems that "DISTINCT" is truncating the values to 255 characters (per Results from the below Query One), whereas "DISTINCTROW" or just "SELECT Docket...." both return the full value - in excess of 255 characters (per Results from the below Query Two).

Is there a way around this? I just want Unique rows. Perhaps the query can be changed to eliminate the need for "DISTINCT"?

Query one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DocketEntriesFiledBy.CaseNumber,
                DocketEntriesFiledBy.docketNum, 
                DocketEntriesFiledBy.Date, 
                DocketEntriesFiledBy.Description, 
                Attorney_Firm.Firm, 
                DocketEntriesFiledBy.FiledByLast, 
                Party_Firms.PartyRole, 
                Party_Firms.CostPerHour, 
                DocketEntriesFiledBy.TimeSpent
FROM DocketEntriesFiledBy INNER JOIN (
                       Attorney_Firm INNER JOIN Party_Firms 
                                     ON Attorney_Firm.Firm = Party_Firms.Firm) 
                          ON DocketEntriesFiledBy.FiledByLast = Attorney_Firm.AttyLast;
```

Query two:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW DocketEntriesFiledBy.CaseNumber,
                   DocketEntriesFiledBy.docketNum, 
                   DocketEntriesFiledBy.Date, 
                   DocketEntriesFiledBy.Description, 
                   Attorney_Firm.Firm, 
                   DocketEntriesFiledBy.FiledByLast, 
                   Party_Firms.PartyRole, 
                   Party_Firms.CostPerHour, 
                   DocketEntriesFiledBy.TimeSpent
FROM DocketEntriesFiledBy INNER JOIN (
                       Attorney_Firm INNER JOIN Party_Firms 
                                     ON Attorney_Firm.Firm = Party_Firms.Firm) 
                          ON DocketEntriesFiledBy.FiledByLast = Attorney_Firm.AttyLast;
```

EDIT: while this is now marked as a duplicate, it does differ from the identified post in two ways. (1) I informed that "DISTINCTROWS" differs and does NOT truncate, and (2) that post is of software over a decade old at this point.

Comment: I don't think so. Even GROUP BY will not handle more than 255 characters. Do you even need memo field in the query? I try hard not to use memo fields at all because of this. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

Comment: I'm not querying against it, but I do need it as a result as it is the description of the docket entry.

Comment: @June7 I checked out that link. Thanks for that! I just made an intermediate query with the uniqueness stuff, then joined it to get the Memo field.